# Spacing between string characters in arced text isn't quite right. (HTML Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, kerning

See here - http://schnell.dreamhosters.com/nysbc/test6.php
JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VauFH/

The piece that draws text...

```
function draw_arc_text(ctx, str, radius){
            ctx.save();
            str = str.toUpperCase();
            var radians_per_letter = 8 * Math.PI/180;                                
            ctx.rotate((105 - (radius/60)) * Math.PI/180);
            for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.rotate(n * radians_per_letter);
                ctx.fillText(str[n], 0, -radius);
                ctx.restore();
            }
            ctx.restore();
        }
```

As you can probably tell the spacing between the text on top of the colored discs is a little off.  I've tried having a set amount of radians/degrees per letter, but the further out in radius you go the more that spacing becomes, so outermost text starts separating at a rapid pace.  I've also tried working out some kind of formula that will incorporate radius into how much spacing each letter gets, but I can't seem to get that quite right either.  Anyone have any ideas?

Also any tweaks in efficiency would be appreciated as well.  I like to be as optimized as I can whenever possible.

Comment: dont know how to help you but cool application!

Comment: Aha wanted to do the same. Can you provide a fiddle? It will be easier to see the code AND the application running. I don't wanna open your source code. For the tweaks, go to code review. There is some int, like  2.0 * Math.PI which could be a variable

Comment: You can get the width of each character using `context.measureText('A').width`. The circumference of a circle is `2 * Math.PI * radius`. So, the angle you will need to shift for each character would be (if I'm thinking clearly this morning) `charWidth / (2 * Math.PI * radius)`

Comment: To start, the `save/restore` inside the for loop isn't necessary. Use `ctx.rotate(radians_per_letter);` and simply get rid of the `save/restore` in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/MdME7/)**

probably a mathematicians worst nightmare :P. The following works though. Basically I just divide the result by the radius / 100. It gives the impression of equal spacing.

Another change I made, was to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of interval. Intervals aren't very performant when compared to `setTimeout` and especially when compare to `requestAnimationFrame` for canvas. You'll notice you don't get a nasty hangup anymore when you leave the tab and go back to it.

I also got rid of the jQuery dependency because all you were using was `document.ready` so it seemed unneeded.

```
function draw_arc_text(ctx, str, radius){
                ctx.save();
                str = str.toUpperCase();

                var textWidth = Math.round(ctx.measureText(str).width);
                var radians_per_letter = (((textWidth/str.length)) * Math.PI/180)/(radius*.01);  

                ctx.rotate(95 * Math.PI/180);

                for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.rotate(n * radians_per_letter);
                    ctx.fillText(str[n], 0, -radius);
                    ctx.restore();
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MdME7/3/ - I'd seen requestAnimationFrame before, but it looked a little weird and complex, but thanks for using it!  I also adjusted what you did in JSFiddle a bit so that the spacing is a bit less, but still based on the radius/100 formula.  I also removed the save/restore within the for loop as was suggested in another part of this question.  To me it looks a little bit more natural, but 'eye of the beholder' and all.  Thanks!

Comment: @MathiasSchnell The save/restore in the for loop is unnecessary overhead. It eats up resources that it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Shmiddty I know, it's gone now.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have much experience with the canvas element, but is there any way you could use CSS' `letter-spacing` property on the text?